# Created basic JSX file to test ReactJS is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, model-view-controller

[here is a pic of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYeYP.png)I created a basic MVC Project and added React.js to it. I have created the following basic component. when executing the app, I get a 500 error.

```js
class Admin extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          test
        </div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Admin />,
    document.getElementById('admin')
);
```

I have added the following packages

```
React.js
React.Core
React.Web
ReactWeb.MVC4
System.Web.Optimization.React
```

Not sure why it is failing on such a basic jsx file. Any Idea what I am missing?

Comment: Did you install [`react-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom)?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. yes have installed react-dom.js and react.js

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what wrong,

I hadn't installed JavaScriptEngineSwitcherV8 and configured it

Package required
JavaScriptEngineSwitcherV8
JavaScriptEngineSwitcherV8. your platform

in ReactJS.cs in App_Start add

```
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
        JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
```

and add references

```
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8;
```

Thanks for everyones responses :)

Comment: This makes sense, therefore i deleted my answer vague trying to help you :)